# Perl Multidimensional Hash in Template Toolkit

Tags: html, perl, template-toolkit

I have the following perl multidimensional hash that is passed from Dancer to Template Toolkit as a hash reference. I am having trouble figuring out how to display it in Template Toolkit.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'TylerMontgomery(2022)' => {
                                   'so' => 1,
                                   'bb' => 1,
                                   'rbis' => 0,
                                   'atbats' => 7,
                                   'runs' => 2,
                                   'hits' => 2
                                 },
          'ChaseLangan(2022)' => {
                                     'runs' => 4,
                                     'hits' => 4,
                                     'atbats' => 5,
                                     'bb' => 0,
                                     'rbis' => 2,
                                     'so' => 1
                                   },
          'BryceJones(2021)' => {
                            'hits' => 2,
                            'runs' => 2,
                            'atbats' => 4,
                            'bb' => 1,
                            'rbis' => 4,
                            'so' => 1
                          },
          'WillGrimes(2021)' => {
                                   'bb' => 0,
                                   'rbis' => 0,
                                   'so' => 1,
                                   'runs' => 1,
                                   'hits' => 2,
                                   'atbats' => 3
                                 },
};
```

I am able to interate the hash within my perl code with the following:

```
    foreach my $name (sort keys %season) {
        printf "%-27.27s", "$name: ";
        foreach my $stat (sort keys %{ $season{$name} }) {
            printf "%-12.12s", "$stat: $season{$name}{$stat} ";
         ## cal. avg
        $season{$name}{AVG} = $season{$name}{hits} / $season{$name}{atbats};
        }

   
    printf "%4s %.3f\n", "avg:", $season{$name}{AVG};
}
```

What I have tried so far for displaying it seems to be somewhat off the mark. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <table style="width:100%; line-height:40px;">   
        <% FOREACH Season = Season %>
        <tr>
          <td width="5">Season.key <% Season.key %></td> 
          <td width="5">Season.val <% Season.value %></td>
          <td width="5">Season.val.atbats <% Season.value.atbats %>
          <td width="5">Season.val.hits <% Season.value.hits %>  
        </tr>   
        <% END %>   
      </table>
```

What ends up getting displayed on web page:

```
HASH(0xabd1ef4)HASH(0xabd1ef4)
Season.key  Season.val  Season.val.atbats   Season.val.hits
```

Comment: Your question does not state what template 'system' you use. Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note: your hash has number of players, but **template** refer to **seasons** -- looks like mismatch.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by 'template system'.  I am using perl->Dancer2->Template Toolkit. Happy to edit the question if there is something more that you believe I should include.

Comment: Look into your question, do you see there any mention of **Dancer**? How do we know what you use if it is not mentioned. Edit your question and put in first two sentences that you use **Dancer** template.

Comment: I have edited my question so to include the mention of Dancer and to show how I iterate the hash of hashes in perl.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Dancer or Dancer2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOREACH` iterates over an array. Iterate over the array returned by `hash.keys`.

```
<% FOREACH id IN payload.keys %>
   <% season = payload.$id %>
   <p><% season.runs %></p>
   <p><% season.atbats %></p>
<% END %>
```

Full code:

```perl
use Template qw( );

my %seasons = (
        'TylerMontgomery(2022)' => {
            'so' => 1,
            'bb' => 1,
            'rbis' => 0,
            'atbats' => 117,
            'runs' => 2,
            'hits' => 2
        },
        'ChaseLangan(2022)' => {
            'runs' => 4,
            'hits' => 24,
            'atbats' => 5,
            'bb' => 0,
            'rbis' => 2,
            'so' => 1
        },
        'BryceJones(2021)' => {
            'hits' => 2,
            'runs' => 2,
            'atbats' => 4,
            'bb' => 2,
            'rbis' => 4,
            'so' => 1
        },
);


my $tt = Template->new({
   START_TAG => '<%',
   END_TAG   => '%>',
});

my $template = <<'__EOS__';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- head definitions go here -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <% FOREACH id IN seasons.keys %>
      <% season = seasons.$id %>
      <p><% season.runs %></p>
      <p><% season.atbats %></p>
      <% END %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
__EOS__

$tt->process(\$template, {
   title   => 'Get Softball Season Stats',
   seasons => \%seasons,
})
   or die($tt->error);
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- head definitions go here -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">


      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>


      <p>2</p>
      <p>117</p>


      <p>2</p>
      <p>4</p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: Don't use `season` for both the collection and the individual seasons. I used better variables names, and you should adjust your data to match.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but when I try with your solution above it only prints out the first player's name --no data, and no other players.

Comment: `id` is the "name". I showed how to access the elements of the hash using it.

Comment: Here is my attempt to implement your answer http://paste.scsys.co.uk/592478 I only changed your variable name 'seasons' to 'payload' because seasons is confusing because the data is comprised of one season and not multiple. I also added an element.

Comment: The code you posted could not possibly have produces the output you posted. `'payload' => %season` is oh so wrong. And if you correct that to `\%season`, you get the correct answer (as you can see from my updated answer).

Comment: Likely I have something wrong but I promise you that the results I am posting are the results that I am getting. If I do: 

 template 'results.tt' => {
 
 'title' => 'Get Softball Season Stats',
 'payload' => \%season,
 
    }, {}; I get blank results (nothing shows up)

Comment: Re "*I promise you that the results I am posting are the results that I am getting.*", I didn't say otherwise.

Comment: When I try:  debug "payload ref: ", \%season; in my dancer route

The output to the console running the app is: 

debug @2020-08-24 17:33:46> payload ref: {'BryceJones(2021)' => {'atbats' => 4,'bb' => 2,'hits' => 2,'rbis' => 4,'runs' => 2,'so' => 1},'ChaseLangan(2022)' => {'atbats' => 5,'bb' => 0,'hits' => 24,'rbis' => 2,'runs' => 4,'so' => 1},'TylerMontgomery(2022)' => {'atbats' => 117,'bb' => 1,'hits' => 2,'rbis' => 0,'runs' => 2,'so' => 1}}

Is that the way it should look?

Comment: Figured it out finally. Dancer uses Template Simple by default and not Template Toolkit. Changing the configuration in config.yml to template Toolkit and enabling TT in my app made everything wor

Comment: "The only markups are INCLUDE, START, END and token" (though it is extensible), so no FOREACH. Yeah, that wouldn't have come close to working X_X